# How do I scrape data from this html tags using python and bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am able to scrape data successfully, how I want to write this to a csv file (comma separated)

I want to extract the elements with class "ui-h2", "help__content help__content--small" and "exam-name". I have the code, but as an output I want

- April 2022, 3 Apr 2022 , UPPSC ACF RFO Mains
- April 2022, 3 Apr 2022 , MPSC Group C

> ```
> <div class="item-name" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exam-4" aria-expanded=false>
>   <div class="ui-h2">April 2022 <span class="ui-tag grey-transparent">14 Exams</span></div>
> </div>
> <div class="item-details collapse " id="exam-4" data-parent="#exam-month">
>   <div class="row">
>       <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
>           <div class="ui-card hover-scale">
>               <a href="https://testbook.com/uppsc-acf-rfo" class="card-link exam-cards">
>                   <div>
>                       <span class="icon calendar-icon"></span>
>                       <span class="help__content help__content--small">3 Apr 2022</span>
>                       <span class="ui-tag green-filled">Official</span>
>                   </div>
>                   <div class="footer-container">
>                       <span class="exam-icon">
>                       <img src="https://blogmedia.testbook.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/uttar-pradesh-logo-png-8-5bbbec3b.png" height="30">
>                       </span>
>                       <span class="exam-name" title="UPPSC ACF RFO Mains">UPPSC ACF RFO Mains</span>
>                       <span class="exam-cta">
>                       Know More <span class="right-icon"></span>
>                       </span>
>                   </div>
>               </a>
>           </div>
>       </div>
>       <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
>           <div class="ui-card hover-scale">
>               <a href="https://testbook.com/mpsc-group-c" class="card-link exam-cards">
>                   <div>
>                       <span class="icon calendar-icon"></span>
>                       <span class="help__content help__content--small">3 Apr 2022</span>
>                       <span class="ui-tag green-filled">Official</span>
>                   </div>
>                   <div class="footer-container">
>                       <span class="exam-icon">
>                       <img src="https://blogmedia.testbook.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/mpsc-logo-1-44a80da2.png" height="30">
>                       </span>
>                       <span class="exam-name" title="MPSC Group C">MPSC Group C</span>
>                       <span class="exam-cta">
>                       Know More <span class="right-icon"></span>
>                       </span>
>                   </div>
>               </a>
>           </div>
>       </div>
> </div>
> </div>
> ```

```
for contents in soup.find_all("div", {"class":"ui-h2"}):
    #print(contents)
    if contents.text is not None:
            #print(contents.text)
            f.write(contents.text+"-")

    for contentspan2 in soup.find_all("span", {"class":"help__content help__content--small"}):
        
        if contentspan2.string is not None:
            #print(contentspan2.string)
            f.write(contentspan2.string+",")
            

        for contentspan in soup.find_all("span", {"class":"exam-name"}):
        
            if contentspan.string is not None:
                #print(contentspan.string)
                f.write(contentspan.string+"\n")
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried in a [mre].

Comment: "I have the code" - cool. Where is it?

Comment: Added the code. Please upvote the question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a list of the rows you want to write to file. Where each element in the list is a dictionary with key:value as the column name:value. Then let pandas do the work.

So given the html you provided:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'row'})

rowList = []
for row in rows:
    cards = row.find_all('div', {'class':re.compile("^ui-card")})
    for card in cards:
        dateStr = card.find('span',{'class':re.compile("^help__content")}).text.strip()
        examName = card.find('span', {'class':'exam-name'}).text
        rowList.append({'date':dateStr,
                        'exam':examName})

df = pd.DataFrame(rowList)
df.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
         date                 exam
0  3 Apr 2022  UPPSC ACF RFO Mains
1  3 Apr 2022         MPSC Group C
```

Comment: NameError: name 're' is not defined. Do I need to import any class?

Comment: you need to `import re`

Comment: I added that , thank you but the new error says   --- "dateStr = card.find('span',{'class':re.compile("^help__content help__content--small")}).text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'  "

Comment: ok, so that means somewhere in your html it's returning None. Also, my code has it as `'class':re.compile("^help__content")`, not `{'class':re.compile("^help__content help__content--small")})`. Can't really help you more than that. You need to work that part out, as I can only work with what you provide in the post and you only provided a limited view of the html to work with.

Comment: Where shall I use my url ? html = ?. I think I am not able to assign url to the html content?

Comment: "I am able to scrape data successfully". According to your post, you have done this. Where's the part of your code that got that html you posted above then? I'm confused as to what you are asking.

Comment: I will open a new ticket to download the images as well. Thank you